# Visual Studio Form Design Error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This has happened to me twice now, the first time it happened I created a new project and copied all of my data to and it worked for a while.  Then the error came back unexpectedly.

I have a simple VB.net project that consists of a single dialog box.  I am getting an error on the Design tab of that dialog box that says

> Could not find type 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'

In the list of references the path for "System" says

> The system cannot find the reference specified

I have tried removing the System reference and re-adding it.  Even closing and opening VS in between.  Every time it gives the same error message.  If I create a new project it has a valid path.

I am using Visual Studio 2013, VB.net

Comment: Yeah, that's not normal.  If that was happening to me, I'd blow away my entire system and reinstall everything from scratch.  You might want to try reinstalling visual studio.  Just run the installer again, it's pretty good about overlaying on a previous install.

Comment: I did do a repair of Visual Studio rebooted and tried again.  It was after the repair operation that I created a new project and moved all the files.  I thought I was in the clear until it happened again.  I am now on my third iteration of the project.

Comment: Nuke your box from orbit. It's the only way to be sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.  I had included a folder with an executable in it.  Whenever I excluded the folder all of the issues went away.